# In The Thing, does the creature ever communicate with humans?

Tags: the-thing-1982, the-thing-2011, the-thing-from-outer-space

I note that in the first screen version of *The Thing*, the monster is both intelligent and uncommunicative — the professor at the base does want to communicate with the alien but it, even to its detriment: it could have assuaged the fears of humans by chatting, displays no interest in communication.

In the remakes, it is a question whether the creature ever actually talks to humans — infected humans may speak to humans, but it is unclear to me that, even if the infected know that they are "things", they say anything they would not have said if they were still human. When the alien is in its fully monstrous or even partially monstrous form, it definitely does not talk. The guy whose hands are transformed and is eventually torched iirc just moans, perhaps showing some interaction between the still-human mind of the man with the alien cells. He moans because he wants to speak perhaps, but the Thing will no longer allow this.

The entire question of infected humans knowing that they have been infected I do not think is clear. The infected biologist, Blair's, behavior kind of suggests that he is acting in the interests of the alien, but maybe the Thing just infected him and the doctor really thinks that destroying the radio is a good idea. On the other hand, he does make a spaceship from scratch so he knows what he is — but it is still not clear that when he speaks to humans, it is not the human mind, under the control (like censorship — perhaps the doctor would want to say, I've been infected, incinerate me, but The Things prevents that — otherwise the doctor gets to say what the doctor would normally say although this doctor knows he has been infected, so his behavior is sort of the interplay between his human side and alien side.)

Comment: The film is purposefully ambiguous about a lot of stuff, but I don't think Blair was infected when he destroyed the radio. I think he was totally human, but wanted to prevented anyone in the camp from being able to leave or call for outside assistance, in order to contain the infection within the camp. I think someone infected him while he was locked away in that cabin. Of course, there is no definitive confirmation of that, because, like I said, the film is purposefully ambiguous about a lot of stuff.

Comment: Destroying the radio sure seems dumb anyway you look at it, but I wonder if the Thing can partially let a human do what it wants, directing only when it needs to. I have posted a question about the weird behavior of Benning while he is in the middle of trasnforming.

Comment: I wouldn't say destroying the radio was dumb, so much as extreme. I think his goal was to prevent the contagion from leaving the camp at all costs, and he was willing to sacrifice the lives of everyone there, including his own, in order to do that. A more measured approach might've been to try and save the people who weren't infected and only kill the people who were, but that would also have been riskier. The best way to ensure that the contagion didn't leave the camp was to be indiscriminate and prevent anyone there from getting out alive. An extreme approach, yes, but not an illogical one.

Comment: I think killing everyone, if possible, was the way to go. As the movie ends, for all we know we live in a world that was transformed 40 years ago. And you know, my life has been pretty much the same. How have things be going for you, assuming you are over 40?

Comment: I don't think either Childs or MacReady were infected at the end, but that's another thing which was deliberately left ambiguous.

Comment: I note that in "Who Goes There?" the alien can definitely talk.

Comment: @mary: does the creature talk as itself or pretending to be human?

Comment: @releseabe  Pretending to be human.  When imitating a madman who had become convinced that he had to scream prayers to be heard by God, it screamed prayers.